# Getting the #id from current URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, uri

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the #anchor part from the current URL with JavaScript.
For example:

> http://my-page.com/index.html#contact-us

Would return `contact-us`.

I could split the URI at the eventual `#` and then take the last piece, but I'm looking for a somewhat nicer and cleaner suggestion. A native (jQuery?) function would be great, but I guess I'm asking for too much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#Properties):

```
location.hash.slice(1);
```

It starts with a `#`, hence `.slice(1)`. Given an arbitrary string, you can use the built-in URL-parsing feature by creating a `<a>` element, and set the href, then *read* other properties, such as `protocol`, `hostname`, `hash`, etc. jQuery example:

```
$('a').attr('href', url)[0].hash;
```

Comment: Neither `splice` nor `slice` is part of `String.prototype`. `location.hash.substr(1)` would do the trick, though.

Comment: @lonesomeday Thanks, was a typo in the code. The explanation used the correct character. EDIT: [`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) on MDN.

Comment: `slice`, of course, is part of `String.prototype`. Apologies for my idiocy.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Ironically, `substr()` itself (unlike `slice()`) is non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

`location.hash.replace(/^#/, "")`

Answer (score 1):

If you work with a variable:

```
var url = "http://my-page.com/index.html#contact-us";

var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
```