# Tabs not switching, but stacking on top of each other. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a small code in JS for 3 tabs in my page. They are meant to help me switch between those tabs without reloading the page. However, the tabs just show up one by one on top of each other and stay there. Could anyone please take a look and tell me what the problem is?
Also, if it's possible - after I've chosen a tab and tried to submit data from one of the tabs using a form and PHP and the validation did not pass, can I add something here so that the same tab stays active and is shown instead of the page just refreshing back to first tab? I would also like the same form stay there even if the form was submited successfully.

This is the JS part:

```
function onTabClick(event) {
    let activeTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
    console.log(activeTabs);
    // deactivate existing active tab and panel
    for (let i = 0; i < activeTabs.length; i++) {
        activeTabs[i].className = activeTabs[i].className.replace('active', '');
    }

    // activate new tab and panel
    event.target.parentElement.className += 'active';
    document.getElementById(event.target.href.split('#')[1]).className += 'active';
}

const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-tab-element');

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', onTabClick, false);
}
```

This is the HTML part. The tabs in UL element and one of the 3 forms. I didn't include all of them just so there isnt too much code here, but they got the right IDs.

```
<ul id="nav-tab" class="nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a class="nav-tab-element" href="#books">Books</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-tab-element" href="#dvds">DVD's</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="nav-tab-element" href="#furniture">Furniture</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

<!-- Tabs -->
<form action="" method="POST">
    <!-- Books Tab -->
    <div class="tab-content active" id="books">
        <div class="book-tab">

            <input type="text" name="sku" placeholder="SKU" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="book-tab">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name of the product" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="book-tab">
            <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Product price" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="book-tab">
            <input type="text" name="size" placeholder="Weight in KG" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <!-- Submit Buttons -->
        <div class="btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear">
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="book">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And lastly, this is the CSS part:

```
.tab-content {
    display: none;
}

.tab-content.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Im very new to JS, therefore any help will be apreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the html for your tab-content

Comment: You can find the HTML part in the middle of the post. An UL list with 3 LI elements.

Comment: do you have `<div class="tab-content" id="books">content</div>` anywhere on your page? If not you need to add it

Comment: Yes @Jujubes, i updated the post and added one of the 3 forms I have in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS.  The CSS displays how the element looks and to some extent how it reacts to user input. JS will add to CSS to make the interactivity of the website

i would suggest using frameworks as they simplify A LOT of functionality. As such, you do not need to recreate the wheel.

my favorite right now is vuejs but i started with jQuery. Both these frameworks are based on javascript.

Another good framework is bootstrap which uses CSS and jQuery among a few others to streamline client side.

Check out **[tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs)** in bootstrap which handles all this functionality for you

If you want a tutorial using a similar approach of your check this out **[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp)**

**Form posting**
You can use AJAX to post the form to where ever and the form will look as though it was not posted. Therefore the tabs wouldnt need to be changed.
If you do not want to use ajax

Using your loop to attach the eventlister add check to see if the window url property is set. [this article covers this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334684/getting-the-id-from-current-url)

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I'm doing this for a Junior position and I'm not allowed to use freamworks unfortunately :D

Comment: The visuals(CSS/SCSS) of your "tabs" needs to be configured for some of your interactivity as well. https://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/